# Doctrine composite key vs UniqueConstraint

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I am not sure, how to define uniqueness of multiple fields.

Am I right that both my following examples do the job?

What's the difference, what you prefer?

First one:

```
/** @ORM\Id */
private $id;

/** @ORM\Id */
private $title;
```

Second one:

```
/** @ORM\Table(name="productitem", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="product_unique", columns={"id", "title"})})
 */
class ProductItem
{
private $id;
private $title;
}
```

Comment: Is your ID a generated value | auto increment or just a plain value/string? Perhaps you can give some examples as a preview of data so it is easier to help you sort your use case.

Comment: I am more interested in general concept. The main difference in all aspects involved. When to use first, when second, when combination?

Comment: Note that Doctrine doc advice against the use of composite key.

Answer (score 1):

I have concluded from my testing at Postgresql DB, that:

1. @Id creates primary key (composite if more properties share this annotation)
2. UniqueConstraints creates unique index

Both guarantee uniqueness. And if I understand it right, the main difference is that primary key can't have null values, but unique index can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your title is unique over your different products you don't need make a composite key out of the title and the id.

If you are sure your product title is unique you could simply use the `title` as a key directly. But it is not recommended to use something that might change over the entity its life time as a primary key (and a product title might of course change during its life time). In such it is better to use a different column with an identifier (surrogate key).

You can simply mark the title as unique with the `unique` attribute, you don't need to use the `UniqueConstraint` for this. Check [the Doctrine documentation chapter: **21.2.1. @Column**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) for more details.

So I suggest following:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\Column(type="int")
 */
private $id;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $title;
```